# Saving huge file in a string JAVA

Tags: java, file, fasta

i'm trying to read a FASTA file into a string in java.
My code works fine with small files, but when I choose a real FASTA file
which includes 5 million chars, so I can use this string, **the program get stucked**.   get stucked= i see no output, and the program becomes with black screen.

```
    public static String  ReadFastaFile(File file) throws IOException{  
    String seq="";
    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file.getPath()))) {
        while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            seq+=line;
            // process line here.
        }
    }
    return seq;
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How can I make it work with huge files also

Comment: @DavidOz what do you mean stuck? Are you debugging in any way to see if it is actually stuck vs. slow?

Comment: Are you processing it line by line (as indicated by `// process line here`) or are you loading it to memory? At *least* use a `StringBuilder` like in David's answer, since concatenation by `+=` becomes very inefficient.

Comment: I dont see an ouput, and the program screen becomes black

Comment: @Kayaman Im saving the lines in a  diffrenet string and send it for the other functions that need this huge string.

Comment: 5 million characters are around 10MB of data. The problem seems to be your using string to concat data instead of something like a StringBuilder. You also need to tell us what you are doing in the //process line here,, that should help get an idea of what is happening. It does seem that you are running out of heap space and the GC is working overtime. What are your -xmx settings?

Comment: @Yogesh_D Thanks for comment. the //process line here was there mistakley, i removed this line. I also tried the sting builder and it also get stucked. im sorry but what is it -xmx settings?

Comment: It's probably the `hasNextLine()` that's the problem. It will look for a line ending, and presumably the file has only a single line, so it will inefficiently read the whole file just to see if it has a line. How does using `BufferedReader` like Pablo suggested work?

Comment: @Kayaman I dont think the _hasNextLine() _ is the problem, becasue with tiny files it works fine. About Pablo's suggestion - i tried to combine with their two solutions - Doing BufferedReader including StringBuilder, but it still get stucked. i guess this is a memory flow, but i have no clue.

Comment: Just because something works fine with tiny files doesn't mean the same approach works with larger files. As was said, 5 million chars is about `10MB`, so it's definitely not a memory issue. Then again it shouldn't really be an issue for even a poorly implemented reading method, so it's looking more and more likely that the issue isn't even with the code you're showing. How many lines does the file have? If I remember anything from fasta/blasta files, they don't have line feeds (because they're not text lines, they're a single sequence). Try adding some debug output to see what's happening.

Comment: @Kayaman You right im sorry. its like 5m~ chars, i dont really know how to count the lines number. ill try, thanks for comments

Comment: You should probably avoid reading the whole file into memory. Try to map into memory with something like `mmb = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r").getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, length)`. Then you can likely access it as `CharBuffer` with `Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(mmb)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a StringBuilder to process big loads of text data:

```
public static String ReadFastaFile( File file ) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder seq = new StringBuilder();

    try( Scanner scanner = new Scanner( file ) ) {
        while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            seq.append( line );
            // process line here.
        }
    }

    return seq.toString();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. it also get stucked.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use BufferedReader to read the file, something like this:

```
public static String readFastaFile(File file) throws IOException {
    String seq="";
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // process line here.
        }
    }
    return seq;
}
```

And also concatenate with StringBuilder like davidbuzatto said.